# Azure SQL cross-database queries returns too many rows with joins

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have a problem with Azure SQL cross-database queries, it looks like if we join data across databases the join is not distributed as input to the external database.

Currently I tried to implement a simple example and therefore I used this starting point: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started-vertical.

As preperation I created 199999 CustomerInformation entries and 200 OrderInformation entries.

Following query works as expected the CustomerInformation Table returns just one row:

```
SELECT o.OrderId, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
  FROM OrderInformation o
  JOIN CustomerInformation c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
 WHERE c.CustomerID = 2
```

[image: Expectd Query plan]

But any query with a join that does not specifiy the CustomerID returns all the rows from the Customers Database.

```
SELECT o.OrderId, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
  FROM OrderInformation o
  JOIN CustomerInformation c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
 WHERE o.OrderId = 1870
```

[image: external database returns too many rows]

Therefore the queries are really slow because the servers transfer to many rows. Do I miss some setting or is it not possible to separate this data with the suggested queries.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Recreating the issue**

*Test data below*

```
SELECT o.OrderId, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
FROM OrderInformation o
JOIN CustomerInformation c ON o.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
WHERE o.OrderId = 155;
```

[image]

All records are returned by the remote query operator, to filter down to one when the inner join is applied.

---

**Some more background on pushing down the predicate to a remote database:**

> Previously, elastic database query could not push parameterized
>   operations to remote databases. As a result, sometimes large row sets
>   had to be unnecessarily brought local to evaluate these operations.
>   With the recent improvements, parameterized operations can now be
>   pushed to remote databases and be evaluated remotely. For a query over
>   an external table and a local table like the following, this can now
>   avoid transferring millions of rows by evaluating the selective filter
>   in the WHERE clause on the remote database:

```
DECLARE @low int
DECLARE @high int
SET @low = 100
SET @high = 200

SELECT c.CustomerId, c.Name, count(OrderId) 
FROM remote_customers c
JOIN local_orders o
ON c.CustomerId = o.CustomerId 
WHERE c.CustomerId > @low and c.CustomerId < @high
GROUP BY c.CustomerId, c.Name;
```

[Source](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/querying-remote-databases-in-azure-sql-db/?v=17.23h)

Above query shows an example of using parameters to define a range from where to read the data. The difference with your problem is that the filtering is happening on the local table.

---

**If we know that this predicate can be pushed down to the remote table**

```
SELECT o.OrderId,c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
FROM CustomerInformation c 
JOIN OrderInformation o on o.CustomerId = c.CustomerID
WHERE o.customerID > 1 and o.Customerid < 10;
```

### [image]

**You could look for a range of customerid's and filter on these**

`MAX()` and `MIN()` functions on `o.Customerid` are  used to get the upper and lower boundaries for `WHERE o.OrderId = 155`

```
DECLARE @MAX INT, @MIN INT;

SELECT @MAX= max(o.Customerid) , @MIN = MIN(o.Customerid)
FROM OrderInformation o 
WHERE o.OrderId = 155;

SELECT o.OrderId,c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
FROM CustomerInformation c 
WHERE c.customerID >= @MIN and c.Customerid <= @MAX;
```

---

**The complete result**

```
 DECLARE @MAX INT, @MIN INT;

 SELECT @MAX= max(o.Customerid) , @MIN = MIN(o.Customerid)
 FROM
 OrderInformation o 
 WHERE o.OrderId = 155;

 ;WITH CTE as(
 SELECT c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
 FROM CustomerInformation c 
 WHERE c.customerID >= @MIN 
 AND c.Customerid <= @MAX
 )

 SELECT o.OrderId, c.CustomerID, c.CustomerName
 FROM CTE c
 INNER JOIN  OrderInformation o
 on o.customerID = c.CustomerID
 where o.Orderid = 155;
```

Pushing down the predicates:

[image]

[Execution plan of this query](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By_WZ_qzE)

```
RemoteQuery="SELECT [c].[CustomerID] [Col1005],[c].[CustomerName] [Col1007] FROM [CustomerInformation] [c] WHERE [c].[CustomerID]&gt;=? AND [c].[CustomerID]&lt;=?"
```

It depends on your data & parameters passed how much this could filter out on the remote table. **YMMV**

---

**Test data**

**Customerinformation (remote db)**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.CustomerInformation (CustomerID int identity(1,1) , CustomerName nvarchar(255));

DECLARE @i int = 1;
WHILE @i < 20000
BEGIN
INSERT INTO CustomerInformation(CustomerName)
VALUES ('Frodo');

SET @i += 1;
END
```

**On the database that will use the external table**

```
CREATE TABLE OrderInformation(OrderId Int identity(1,1), CustomerId int,Ordervalue int);


SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @i int = 1;
WHILE @i < 200 
BEGIN
INSERT INTO OrderInformation(CustomerId,Ordervalue)
Values (@I,111);

set @i += 1;
END

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  [dbo].CustomerInformation(
    CustomerID [int],
CustomerName nvarchar(255))
    WITH  
(  
    DATA_SOURCE = Stackoverflow  
);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the elastic query overview,

> Elastic queries can now push SQL parameters to the remote databases for execution.

Try including the order.CustomerID in your WHERE clause, to force the CustomerID to be sent with the query to the remote db.

```
WHERE o.OrderId = 1870 AND c.CustomerID = o.CustomerID
```

[from Microsoft's Azure SQL Database elastic query overview (preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-overview)

Otherwise, I saw a similar issue once when working with regular linked tables for an on-premise MS SQL server, and it turned out to be permission issue on the remote host. No ability of the reading server to read remote indexes was causing all rows to be returned like you are seeing.